# CherryPy install problem on web hosting provider

Tags: linux, python

I have a linux based web hosting provider (fatcow.com) that doesn't give any command line access and won't run the setup script for CherryPy (python web server) for me.

Is there any way to run get around this limitation so that I have a working install of CherryPy?

I also posted this on stackoverflow, but it might be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't start the inbuilt HTTP server, or run the Python scripts through WSGI, there's no other way to do this.